# MEF based plugin system can't instance my plugins

Tags: c#, plugins, reflection, mef

I've implemented a very small plugin system based on `C# with MEF`. The problem is, none of my plugins are instanced. In the `Aggregate-Catalog` I can see `my plugin listed`. But, after I'll compose these parts, there isn't my plugin in the plugin list, what I'm doing wrong?

Here's a snippet of my code:

Plugin-Loader:

```
    [ImportMany(typeof(IFetchService))]
    private IFetchService[] _pluginList;
    private AggregateCatalog _pluginCatalog;
    private const string pluginPathKey = "PluginPath";
    ...

    public PluginManager(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        var dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[pluginPathKey]);
        //Here's my plugin listed...
        _pluginCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(dirCatalog);

        var compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(_pluginCatalog);
        compositionContainer.ComposeParts(this);
     }
     ...
```

And here, the plugin itself:

```
[Export(typeof(IFetchService))]
public class MySamplePlugin : IFetchService
{
    public MySamplePlugin()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plugin entered");
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I copied your code inside console application and it worked without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tested working sample.

Compile class library with code inside PluginNameSpace namespace and place it to the 'Test' folder which will be inside console app exe folder.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using ConsoleApplication;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public interface IFetchService
    {
        void Write();
    }

    class PluginManager
    {
        [ImportMany(typeof(IFetchService))]
        public  IFetchService[] PluginList;

        public PluginManager()
        {
            var dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\Test");

            var pluginCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(dirCatalog);
            var compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(pluginCatalog);
            compositionContainer.ComposeParts(this);
         } 
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pluginManager = new PluginManager();

            foreach (var fetchService in pluginManager.PluginList)
            {
                fetchService.Write();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

// Separate class library
namespace PluginNameSpace
{
    [Export(typeof(IFetchService))]
    public class MySamplePlugin : IFetchService
    {
        public void Write()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Plugin entered");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have read my post? In this post, I've said, that my plugin is listed in the AggregateCatalog. Only the ComposeContainer isn't able to compose these parts. My Plugin is a seperate library. I've solved the problem by myselfe. The Interface IFetchService should seperated by an own library. This library should be referenced from both sides. Now my plugins are loaded and instanced.